# Force modified contributor role to be re-approved on edit?

Tags: user-roles, customization

I gave the Contributor role edit_published_posts capability. Contributor submits a post, Admin publishes it. Now Contributor can edit it without approval. Is there a way to force it to be re-approved by Admin?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow a userclass to edit a published page and save as a draft - but not publish w/o admin approval](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/allow-a-userclass-to-edit-a-published-page-and-save-as-a-draft-but-not-publish)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `'wp_insert_post_data'` hook to check if the user is not an admin, and if the post status is allready "published" change it to "pending":

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data','re_aprove');
function re_aprove($data , $postarr){
    global $current_user;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    //check if current user is not admin
    if (!current_user_can('manage_options')){ 
        if ($data['post_status'] = "publish"){
            $data['post_status'] = "pending";
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Comment: But then the post disappears from public view...